# Spring Batch Job scheduler stops being executing after several runs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduler

On a project we have to run a job that starts periodically (every 5 minutes on QA env now) that processes some assignments for 40k users.
We had decided to utilize Spring Batch because it fits perfectly and implemented it with pretty much default configuration (e.g. it uses `SyncTaskExecutor` under the hood).
Okay, so, there is a job that consists of a single step with:

1. out-of-box `HibernatePagingItemReader`
2. custom `ItemProcessor`that performs lightweight calculations in memory
3. custom `ItemWriter` that persists data to the same PostgreSQL db via several JPQL and native queries.

The job itself is scheduled with `@EnableScheduling` and is being triggered every 5 mins by cron expression:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.assignment-rules}")
void processAssignments() {
  try {
    log.debug("Running assignment processing job");
    jobLauncher.run(assignmentProcessingJob, populateJobParameters());
  } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
    log.error("Job processing has failed", e);
  }
}
```

Here is a cron expression from `application.yml`:

```
job:
  assignment-rules: "0 0/5  * * * *"
```

The problem is that it stops being scheduled after several runs (different amount of runs every time). Let's take a look into the Spring Batch schema:

```sql
select ex.job_instance_id, ex.create_time, ex.start_time, ex.end_time, ex.status, ex.exit_code, ex.exit_message
from batch_job_execution ex inner join batch_job_instance bji on ex.job_instance_id = bji.job_instance_id
order by start_time desc, job_instance_id desc;
```

[image]
And then silence. Nothing special in logs.
The only thing I believe could make sense is that there are two more jobs running on that instance. And one of them is time consuming because it sends emails via SMTP.
The entire jobs schedule is:

```
job:
  invitation-email: "0 0/10 * * * *"
  assignment-rules: "0 0/5  * * * *"
  rm-subordinates-count: "0 0/30 * * * *"
```

Colleagues, could anybody point me out the way this problem could be troubleshooted?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I believe that the cause might be either in spring batch or the scheduler miss-configuration, but again, both are "default".

Comment: It seems the `SyncTaskExecutor` is sync but it is lost the jobs scheduled since. it would be great if you can log the `threads`, looks like the `queue of threads` by default is small, if you custom it might work. Try it.

Comment: @JonathanJohx, that is exactly what I've been meditating on all the morning. And yep, looks like SMTP sender holds the thread. I'll try to move it to separate thread pool and will definitely let know if that is the cause

Comment: Sure, let me know about it @IgorPetrov

Comment: @JonathanJohx sorry, forgot to reach you out. You were right, the problem was in another long running task scheduled by same `SyncTaskExecutor`. Splitting up schedulers to different threads solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I will be thankful if you upvote any of my answers as gratitude :) I will remove this comment after you do it :) thanks. have a good week. @IgorPetrov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the default `SyncTaskExecutor` to launch jobs is not safe in your use case as all jobs will be executed by a single thread. If one of the jobs takes more than 5 minutes to run, next jobs will pile up and fail to start at some point.

I would configure a `JobLauncher` with an asynchronous `TaskExecutor` implementation (like `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) in your use case. You can find an example in the [Configuring a JobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher) section (See "Figure 3. Asynchronous Job Launcher Sequence").

Apart from the task executor configured to be used by the `JobLauncher` of Spring Batch, you need to make sure you have the right task executor used by Spring Boot to schedule tasks (since you are using `@EnableScheduling`). Please refer to the [Task Execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-task-execution-scheduling.html) section for more details.